# Letting a user create only one post and saving that post into user profile

Tags: python, django

I have an app that users can create a category page. I want to modify it to where user can only create one. And that page to be displayed in a profile page. I'm using userena for user-profile system. 
Thing is I'm not sure how to restrict the user to create only one category page. and how that page is to be saved so the creator can have some access(like editing/deleting)

This is my views.py:

```
@login_required
def add_category(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)

    else:
        form = CategoryForm()

    return render(request, 'main/add_category.html', {'form':form})
```

I can create edit/delete view just not sure how to let users to create one page only.

Models.py

```
class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = uuslug(self.name,instance=self, max_length=100)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self): 
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return 'category/%s' % (self.slug)
```

forms.py

```
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="plz enter")
    likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    slug = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields =('name',)
```

Edit:

{{post.category}}

Comment: I your `Category` model, you should have an `author` field. In your `add_category` view, check `Category.objects.filter(author=request.user).exists()`

Comment: oh yeah why didn't i think of that, let me try it

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini wait not sure about author field? hmmm.....let me upload my models.py

Comment: You have to add that field (a ForeignKey to User). If you show me your CategoryForm I can give you a step-by-step solution.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I was just googling about author field, I edited forms.py. Thanks Andrea,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want each user to create at most one category. Therefore, first of all, you need to know whether a user has already created a category or not.

There can be many ways to do so, what I'd recommend is to add an `author` field to your model:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    # Here I've chosen to use a ForeignKey, 
    # but you can also use a OneToOneField.
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, unique=True)

    ...
```

After adding the field, remember to [generate and run the migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/):

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations
$ python manage.py migrate
```

This new `author` field should be set automatically and must not appear in your form. Given that you are already using `fields = ['name']` (and you are not using `exclude`), you do not have to modify your `CategoryForm`.

Now you have to modify your view so that it does two things:

1. it sets the `author` field upon creation;
2. it checks whether the current user has already created a `Category` or not.

```
@login_required
def add_category(request):
    if Category.objects.filter(author=request.user).exists():
        # This user has already created another category.
        # Show him an error message, or redirect him to another page.
        return ...

    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = Category(author=request.user)
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST, instance=category)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return index(request)

    else:
        form = CategoryForm()

    return render(request, 'main/add_category.html', {'form':form})
```

Comment: I think I get almost of them, I would've never thought of using it like that...I get AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'Auth_USER_MODEL'
error tho,

Comment: @haloyoba: `AUTH` is uppercased

Comment: All of sudden i get OperationalError at /

no such column: main_category.author_id ....I tried to fix this it's not working do you know why? I'll upload where it's getting from, if you can take a look at it I would be appreciated

Comment: maybe I'm getting this because I deleted my migration files ?? don't have any post....is that why

Comment: Whenever you change your models, you have to generate the migrations and run them

Comment: Yes ofc, I did make migrations, and migrate but then when I open the browser I get operationError

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99346/discussion-between-andrea-corbellini-and-haloyoba).

Comment: Hey Andrea, are you there? I've been having problem implementing thumbnail for a few days now, can you help me? I tried easy thumbnail/sorl thumbnail/imagekit none of them works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34534578/ioerror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory-static-in-env-media-root-http-i-img?noredirect=1#comment56811691_34534578

Comment: Hello, after fixing it like you told me I'm having trouble making new category page in admin page. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: @haloyoba: yes, please open a new question

Comment: Hello Andrea, do you mind taking a look at this post<I've been struggling for this for a while now>; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520966/how-to-save-image-that-got-extracted?noredirect=1#comment56995309_34520966